# LyX, listings, cannot get return to the line in the last part of a code

Tags: listings, lyx

**Reformulation:**

I am starting from the Julia code as follows (in VS-Code):

```
fout = open("harmoniques-spheriques_l3_m1.dat","w")

for θ in 0.00:0.02:6.50
    for φ in 0.00:0.02:6.50
        Y = SphericalHarmonics.sphericalharmonic(θ, φ, l, m)
        println(fout, "$θ", "   ", "$φ", "                      ", "$Y")
    end
end

close(fout)
```

I insert this code in Lyx --> Listings. After compiling the listing I obtain a curious pdf result: the terms "end", "end", "close(fout)", as well as the part associated with the graph (which is not represented here) are grouped together into a single line. Like this:

```
 p r i n t l n ( f o u t , "$θ " , "  " , "$φ " , "  " , "$Y ”)endendclose(fout)#graphfile = raw”harmoniques−
```

I expected a compiled listing layout close to the one in the Julia code (i.e., as in VS-Code). How can I circumvent this problem?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Welcome! It might be easier for others to help you if you post a minimal .lyx file. Note that a .lyx file is just a text file so you can paste it in as code. Please read here: https://wiki.lyx.org/FAQ/MinimalExample

Comment: Can you please post a LyX file that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: Aquarelle, you can edit you post instead of adding information with answers. Can you open the LyX file with a text editor and post the content in the question?

Answer (score 1):

In the println instruction, `"$\$$$Y"` must be replaced by `"$\$Y$"`
And everything is back to normal.
Sorry for this stupid mistaken.